# Dynamic TableLayout and Control

Tags: vb.net, tablelayout

created dynamic table layout and add some controls in to that table layout.my code

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnLoad(e As EventArgs)
MyBase.OnLoad(e)
  dynamicTable.ColumnCount = 5
 dynamicTable.RowCount = 1
For i = 1 To 5
    Dim button= New button()
    button.Text = i.ToString()
    dynamicTable.SetColumn(button, i)    
    dynamicTable.Controls.Add(button)
Next
```

Next
End Sub

Now i added 5 buttons to the table layout. 
Now i am going to click on the button. How can i know ,on which button i clicked ?

Comment: Set Button Name and add handler for that button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
  Dim dynamicTable As New TableLayoutPanel

        dynamicTable.ColumnCount = 5
        dynamicTable.RowCount = 1

        For i = 1 To 5

            Dim button = New Button()
            button.Name = "button" & i
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf Click1
            Button.Text = i.ToString()
            dynamicTable.SetColumn(button, i)
            dynamicTable.Controls.Add(button)

        Next

        Me.Controls.Add(dynamicTable)


  Private Sub Click1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

       If sender.Name = "button1" Then
            MsgBox("Hi")
       End If

  End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the response
sorry to say that am using vb.net..

i tried your code in  table layout_click event in my application.

( If sender.Name = "button1" Then
            MsgBox("Hi")
       End If)


but 
while debugging this event didn't fired

what can i do ?

Comment: its not `table layout_click` event. Its own function add to handler of all button. did you under stand.